# Find a set of measure zero, but area greater is than zero.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, area

My question is to find a set $S$(let $S$ be subset of $R^2$  ) of measure zero, but area greater is than zero. 
What I try to do... first of all set $S$ must be bounded (because definition of area only works for bounded set) Secondly if set $S$ is bounded $S$ musn't be closed (for compact set measure of zero is equal to area zero)...

Comment: How are you defining area as opposed to measure?  Usually when I see people use measure in $\Bbb R^2$ they define area to be the measure of the measurable sets.  There are other measures, but there is no reason for them to agree in value.

Comment: Area - integral of$ \mathbb{1}$ characteristic function  (on class we also call this Jordan measure)
on the class we define only measure zero. Set is meassure if for every epsilon > 0 S can be cover the most countably many rectangle area less than epsilon.

Comment: @LovroSindičić Which integral? The Lebesgue integral across a set of measure $0$ is always $0$.

Comment: Let's $S$ be our subset and $\pi$(S) area of $S$. Let also A be recetangle such that A>S - than we define $\pi(S)$=$\iint_A \ \chi_{S}$

Comment: @LovroSindičić But integral *in what sense*? The Lebesgue integral of the characteristic function of any measure-zero set is always zero, so you must be talking about some other type of integral (of which there are lots - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Other_integrals)) - which one?

Comment: @NoahSchweber he means integral in the Riemann sense and Peano-Jordan finitely additive measure.

Comment: @nullUser That seems reasonable, but I'd still like them to clarify.

Comment: @Noah I'm sorry integral is Riemann

Comment: Aren't all Jordan measurable sets also Lebesgue measurable? And then its repective measures agree, see https://books.google.nl/books?id=CoSIe7h5mTsC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=Set+with+JOrdan+measure+positive+and+Lebesgue+measure+0&source=bl&ots=lSNsioG8ic&sig=8keTKEymd7eloTnmOXs9H4u0S9I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9x4eww4LTAhVNrRQKHZ-CCE8Q6AEISzAH#v=onepage&q=Set%20with%20JOrdan%20measure%20positive%20and%20Lebesgue%20measure%200&f=false